# Lower rep needed to create tags on beta sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, beta-phase

At the moment beta sites like math don't have many tags, so I suggest moving the rep requirement to 101 (the amount of rep you get if you associate with another site).

It's fairly frustrating having to choose a tag unrelated to your question because there isn't one that is. I'm sure this puts off users who come from other StackExchange sites only to find that there are few tags, especially if you're on, say, an iPhone because the tag drop-down takes ages to appear, if ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe someone must have used a site a bit before they can create useful tags.  I think most of the beta sites have too many tags – I don’t find a tag with only 1 or 2 questions in it useful.

Maybe we need a “please-retag” tag on all the beta sites, and then if a user can’t find a tag that match their questions, they can you “please-retag”, and then a longer established user can retag with the correct tag or create a new tag if needed.

*(I am not saying that the current rep required to create tags on Beta site is correct, just that 101 is too low.)*

Comment: well 101 is the amount of rep you get if you have assocaited with other sites, meaning you've had some previous SE experience. Just because you haven't asked a question on a site, doesn't mean you don't know about the topic of the site.

Comment: But your please-retag tag is a better idea!